# textFieldShouldReturn not being called in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield

We're trying to figure out how to get the keyboard to hide, but we're having problems getting the `textFieldShouldReturn` to fire. Why?

This is what has been done:

*.h

```
@interface MultiSalesViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

*.c

```
txtCardNumber.delegate = self;

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Also, the `textField` has its delegate set to Files Owner in Interface Builder. One odd thing, is that the viewController's `- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` is working.

How to get the hiding of the keyboard working?

Comment: i wasn't aware you could put objective-c code in a *.c file and have it work!

Comment: Lol yea, surely it's .m?

Answer (score 81):

I had the exact same issue and it was because I forgot to set the delegate for the text field in interface builder to 'files owner'.

Answer (score 28):

I had the same problem and, as Warren Crowther suggested, I managed to solve it by holding down CTRL and dragging from the TextBox to the "File's Owner" label.

(Gosh, I miss Visual Studio sometimes...!!)

[image]

(Apologies for repeating what's already been said, but I thought a screenshot might be useful !)

Answer (score 12):

I had the delegate set and everything. But I was using a UITextView instead of UITextfield...

Perhaps this will help someone trying to figure why delegate methods are not fired.

Comment: +1 for advice that could help someone in a edge case.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, because that's exactly what was happening to me. Ugh

Comment: is it possible for it to still work with a UITextView ?

Comment: UITextView: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703754/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-for-uitextview-with-return-key

Answer (score 10):

I see you put it in your code, but for future visitors, add this to your code:

> yourTextField.delegate = self;

Answer (score 6):

I think you are using xib. If so You also need to set delegate over there. Do Right Click on your UITextfiled in xib and you will have delegate option drag it to your file owner.

Answer (score 3):

be sure that your `MultiSalesViewController` implements the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol:

`@interface MultiSalesViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>`

try adding `[self becomeFirstResponder];` after `[textField resignFirstResponder];`

---

edit:
just another thought.. does your `UITextField` have a value set for `returnKeyType`?

`txtCardNumber.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;`

i'm not sure if this has to be set for the function to work

Comment: Right now the textFieldShouldReturn callback is NOT firing at all despite the view controller implementing UITextFieldDelegate. This is odd because the textFieldDidEndEditing callback is. This seems odd because both are defined as part of the UITextFieldDelegate. So, my question is why is one firing and not the other?

Answer (score 3):

following is answer from Mike Gledhill and Warren Crowther updated with xcode 5 screenshot.

(to set UITextField delegate, press and hold ctrl + drag from the UITextField to the "File's Owner" yellow button, shown in image below.  if UITextField delegate not set, textFieldShouldReturn method never gets called).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had everything wired up just right and `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField` was still not being called!

As a work around I configured a method to fire on 'EditingDidEnd':

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to Connection Inspector and connect delegate to view controller .thats it .

Answer (score 0):

Checklist to get it to work:

> - Did you set your controller as **delegate** to UITextField Instance?
> - Make sure controller is not being deallocated by either assigning to property (Autorelease) or explicit retaining it.