# swift 3.0 - UITextFieldDelegate protocol extension not working

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextfielddelegate

I try implement `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol in `ViewController`. I have started with [apple tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson3.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH22-SW1). I implemented the same such as it is on tutorial but it doesn't work. (XCODE 8)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    // MARK: Properties

    @IBOutlet weak var recipeNameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var recipeNameLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        recipeNameField.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: Actions

    @IBAction func onSetDefaultRecipeClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        recipeNameField.text = "Deafult recipe name"
    }

    // MARK: UITextFieldDelegate
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        print("return")
        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: Is "return" printed into console when you print from keyboard?

Comment: nope. nothing happens

Comment: Ok, is `viewDidLoad` called at all? You can check it with a breakpoint or with another `print("view did load")`

Comment: yes it is called. Weird...

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11432348/1689376

Comment: I removed all widgets and I have created since began and it works. I don' know why;/

Comment: Yep, sometimes it's better to start all over again :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete the first line in textField delegate.

Comment: `func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        print("return")
        return true

    }`