# How do I dismiss a UITextView using the Done keyboard button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-softkeyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to dismiss keyboard for UITextView with return key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703754/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-for-uitextview-with-return-key)

I have a UITextView and have done the following:

```
text.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
```

so that I can dismiss the keyboard when I press on done, however when i click on Done all it does is to go into the next line. How can I change this behavior? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 56):

There’s no `shouldReturn` on `UITextView`, but you can implement `UITextViewDelegate` and watch for insertions:

```
- (BOOL) textView: (UITextView*) textView
    shouldChangeTextInRange: (NSRange) range
    replacementText: (NSString*) text
{
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Edit: And yes, sorry, this is a [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703754).