# Hide Virtual Keyboard of UITextView when 'Done' Presses

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitextview, iphone-softkeyboard

I want to hide (`resignFirstResponder`) the virtual keyboard of `UITextView` when 'Done' presses. Theres no 'Did End on Exit' in `UITextView`. In `UITextField` i connect the 'Did End on Exit' with an `IBAction` and call `resignFirstResponder` method. How can i do this with `UITextView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Swift version of the accessory "Done" button:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

// In viewDidLoad()

    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    toolbar.items = [
        UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil),
        UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, target: nil, action: "handleDone:")
    ]

    self.textView.inputAccessoryView = toolbar

// -----------------

func handleDone(sender:UIButton) {
    self.textView.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The correct way to handle this is to add a done button in an `inputAccessoryView` to the `UITextView`. The `inputAccessoryView` is the bar that sometimes appears above the keyboard.

In order to implement the `inputAccessoryView` simply add this method (or a variation thereof) and call it in `viewDidLoad`.

```
- (void)addInputAccessoryViewForTextView:(UITextView *)textView{

//Create the toolbar for the inputAccessoryView
UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
[toolbar sizeToFit];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

//Add the done button and set its target:action: to call the method returnTextView:
toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(returnTextView:)],
                       nil];

//Set the inputAccessoryView
[textView setInputAccessoryView:toolbar];

}
```

Then handel the button being pressed by implementing the action method you called with `resignFirstResponder`.

```
- (void) returnBreakdown:(UIButton *)sender{

[self.textView resignFirstResponder];

}
```

This should result in a working "Done" button appearing in a standard toolbar above the keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming by the "Done" button you mean the return key. It's not as intuitive as you might think. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703754/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-for-uitextview-with-return-key) covers it pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

you could add this to an action if you want to be able to use your return key 
        `[[self view] endEditing: YES];`

Comment: I like this solution. The equivalent in Xamarin.IOS is 
    View.EndEditing(true);

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you declare support for the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol.

`@interface ...ViewController : UIViewController`` in .h file. 
 In .m file, implement below method

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
[textView resignFirstResponder];
return NO;
}
return YES; }
```