# Hide Keyboard then push done in UITextView

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uitextview

I'm trying to make so that the keyboard hides then i push done on a UITextView. I no have to do it on an UITextField. But because i need multiline text i need an UITextView. I have done it for UITextField this way `this.txtDefault.ShouldReturn += (textField) => { textField.ResignFirstResponder(); return true; };` But it seemed that the UITextView doesn't have an ShouldReturn method. Have can i do it.
Best Regard Morten Starck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use a UITextField for your purposes instead?

Apple's docs on [UITextView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html) say there isn't a selector for `ShouldReturn` at all, hence MonoTouch isn't going to be able to make it work either.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703754/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-for-uitextview-with-return-key) is another SO question on the subject, but these guys are using Obj-C.  They suggest using `ShouldChangeTextInRange`, but that would be ugly.  Using UITextField would be easier if you can make it work for your case.