# Hiding Keyboard on UITextView

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I'd like to thanks you in advance for your answers. I read all stuff about this but I couldn't solve it.

I know how to hide keyboard on UITextField, just like this:

```
    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [placename resignFirstResponder];
    [address resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
```

But I also have an UITextView and I don't know how to hide it. I don't want to hide it with a button I want to hide it with a "Done" in the return.

I read something like this:

```
[textField setReturnKeyType: UIReturnKeyDone];
```

But... how and where to implement it? I'm new on this so I need to know it step by step,please.

Thanks so much.
(Sorry I'm not able to send an image...new user ;) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its easy. Have textview delegate in your controller and add following method.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

There is one disadvantage using this, user can not write multi line statements. To solve this you can have a create view over keyboard and have button over there and add action to resign your textview.

[Credit to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703754/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-for-uitextview-with-return-key)

Answer (score 0):

Additional to @JanakNirmal Answers, the code for the .h and .m. Works fine for me.

#### .h

```c
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textField; // connected with IB
@end
```

#### .m

```c
@interface ViewController ()
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Done key and hide keyboard 
    [self.textField setDelegate:self];
    [self.textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range  replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
@end
```