# UITextView not resigning

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextview

Ok I have exhausted google and this site looking for an answer and cannot find one. I currently have a UITextView (postMessage) and the keyboard for it will not disappear. I have tried every possible code combination to make it dismiss but it simply will not.

I have tried doing the return key method

```
- (BOOL) textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]){
    //MainViewController *mvc = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    //[mvc.view endEditing:YES];
    //[[self view] endEditing: YES];
    //[self.postMessage becomeFirstResponder];
    //[self.topLayer endEditing:YES];
    //[self.view endEditing:YES];
    //[self.collectionView endEditing:YES];
    //[self.postMessage.editable = NO];
    //[postMessage resignFirstResponder];
    [self.postMessage resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}else{
    return YES;
}
}
```

I also have tried using a UIToolBar with a UIBarButton

```
-(IBAction)done:(id)sender {
[self keyboardIsHidden];
[[self view] endEditing: YES];
[self.postMessage becomeFirstResponder];
[self.topLayer endEditing:YES];
[self.view endEditing:YES];
[self.collectionView endEditing:YES];
//[self.postMessage.editable = NO];
[self.postMessage resignFirstResponder];

keyboardBar.hidden = YES;
NSLog(@"done");
}
```

And nothing..... I have used NSLogs to make sure that both methods are being called, but the keyboard will not resign. I have also use and if statement to check to make sure the UITextView (postMessage) is firstResponder and it is.

In my project I have 2 views (not view controllers) a bottom layer view and top layer. The user pulls the top layer up into view. I also have a UICollectionView.

I have noticed that when I press the return key on the keyboard or the 'Done' key on my UIToolBar the UICollectionView reloads the data.

I do have the UITextViewDelegate set on the .h.
I also have postMessage.delegate = self in my ViewDidLoad

Thanks!
-Mike

Comment: make sure you have set delegate to the textview

Comment: Check delegate is set for textview & if you are using IB then check outlet connection.

Comment: Have you set the delegate in ViewDidLoad method?

Comment: You can refer to the following link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703754/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-for-uitextview-with-return-key

Comment: I have connected in the storyboard the delegate from my textView (called postMessage) to the UIViewController. I also have in my viewdidload I have (myUITextView).delegate = self;

Answer (score 1):

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

    if([string isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

i am using this work fine

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range
 replacementText:(NSString *)text
{

if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {

    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    // Return FALSE so that the final '\n' character doesn't get added
    return NO;
}
// For any other character return TRUE so that the text gets added to the view
return YES;
}
```

or create a button ..

```
-(IBAction)btnclicked{

[txtvw resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach your TextField Delegate with File owner , Clean build and run Project