# Move From UITextField to UITextView When Return Pressed

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview, resignfirstresponder, becomefirstresponder

I have several text views in my app.  All but one are UITextField, and the other is a UITextView, located right in the middle of the others.  This is due to this section needing much more room for the user to type and see all of what they are typing out.  I have it set up so that when the user presses next on the keyboard, it goes to the next field, using this code:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == firstName) {
        [firstName resignFirstResponder];
        [lastName becomeFirstResponder];
    } else if (textField == lastName) {
        [lastName resignFirstResponder];
        [theRequest becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == theRequest) {
        [theRequest resignFirstResponder];
        [theDetails becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == theDetails) {
        [theDetails resignFirstResponder];
        [textdate becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == textdate) {
        [textdate resignFirstResponder];
        [location becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == location) {
        [location resignFirstResponder];

    }
    return YES;
}
```

Everything goes fine until I get to the UITextView.  When I click next there, it simply pushes the cursor down a line.  How can I get it to respond to simply go to the next field?

Also, when clicking Next in location, it goes back to first name.  How can that be setup to just dismiss keyboard?

Comment: Text views are meant for entering multiple lines of text. The return key is meant for entering those multiple lines of text. You need another way to indicate that the focus should move to the next field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try two ways:

1) Use function

```
-(BOOL)textViewShouldReturn:(UITextView *)textView
```

to realize needed behaviour.

2) Read this:

[How to dismiss keyboard for UITextView with return key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703754/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-for-uitextview-with-return-key)

and adapt those solutions to your neeeds.

Comment: There is no such thing as the `textViewShouldReturn` method.

Comment: Sorry, my answer is incomplete. You are right - this function must be defined first. My fault.

Comment: Defined how? How will it be called?

Comment: Thru `textViewDidChange` or `textView: shouldChangeTextInRange:`. First way in my answer is just a variant of second way, sorry.

Comment: You really should clarify your answer. As it stands, it sound like there are two choices but the 1st one isn't valid on its own.

Comment: As one of possible variants it can be defined as `- (BOOL)textViewShouldReturn:(UITextView *)textView {
  [self performSelector:@selector(textViewDidChange:) withObject:textView];
  return NO;
}`

Comment: But there is no such delegate method as `textViewShouldReturn:`. It won't ever get called.

Comment: I found this solution in `UIInputToolbar` by Brandon Hamilton (https://github.com/brandonhamilton/inputtoolbar/tree/master/UIInputToolbarSample/Classes/UIInputToolbar). There you can find necessary code for definition of this function and delegate. This function calls `- (BOOL)expandingTextViewShouldReturn:(BHExpandingTextView *)expandingTextView;`

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I like to do when I have multiple textfields, is use the tag instead of checking one by one. First, in the `interface builder`/`storyboard`, set the `tag` property of each `UITextField` in ascending order, (it's better if you start at 1). Than, your `textFieldShouldReturn:` reduces to something like this.

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UIView * nextView = [self.scrollView viewWithTag:textField.tag + 1];
    if ([nextView respondsToSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder)])
        [nextView becomeFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```

And about your question about going to the next field from a `UITextView`, I agree with the second option from Sergey's answer

Comment: Why would you see if the view responds to `becomeFirstResponder`? `UIView` extends `UIResponder` so all views respond to that selector.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but since I managed to get my answer, I thought I share it.

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
{
    [textView performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];

    return YES;
}
```

I was told that with the `afterDelay:0.1` it makes a difference in the device, where using simulator we can use `afterDelay:0.0`.