# Return UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I am running into an issue when trying to return the keyboard in my UITextView when the return button is selected.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 

    self.captionArea.delegate = self 
} 

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    NSUInteger newLength = [self.captionView.text length] + [text length] - range.length;
    return (newLength > 30) ? NO : YES;

    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;

}
```

Any ideas why this is giving me issues? The view is just going to a newline, not returning.

Comment: Your method returns before your if statement is reached.

Comment: Why are you using a `UITextView` instead of a `UITextField` is the length can only be 30 or less and only on one line?

Comment: Did you figure this out? If so, please accept my answer below and close this question as resolved.

Comment: You need to be using a UITextField for this not a UITextView.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely, your code simply never reaches the point where you ask text view to resign first responder. Try putting your `resignFirstResponder` method call above all return statements.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }    

    NSUInteger newLength = [textView.text length] + [text length] - range.length;
    return (newLength > 30) ? NO : YES;
}
```

Also, you should think about switching to `UITextField` if all you're trying to make  is a simple single line text field, because `UITextView` doesn't come with standard methods to hide the keyboard. As explained in this popular [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703754/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-for-uitextview-with-return-key), "*hitting the return and hiding the keyboard for a UITextView does not follow the interface guidelines*".

The method described above is a simple hack and don't work properly if user enters the text which contains `\n` (newline) character.

Comment: You should also return `NO` if you resign first responder since you don't want to bother with the length check nor do you want the newline added to the text view.

Comment: This code will fail is the user pastes in text that happens to include a newline.

Comment: One other issue (from the OP's original code). Why does this code check `self.captionView.text` instead of`textView.text`?