# textFieldShouldReturn method of UITextview

Tags: ios, keyboard, xcode5, uitextview

Needing to present user a multiline text field for comment entry, I am using a UITextView instead of a UITextField. I would like to use `textFieldShouldReturn` on my UITextView to send the data to server. How might I do that? Based on my readings so far, the method is only applicable to UITextField. So what is the equivalent for UITextView?

Comment: Try this ->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703754/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-for-uitextview-with-return-key

Answer (score 4):

By adding the UITextViewDelegate to your viewControllerHeader

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextViewDelegate>
```

This'll allow you access to the UITextViewDelegate methods of which there are a couple of which should allow you to know when the user has either pressed return or let you know when they have finished editing, for example

```
 - (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView{

//From here you can action your methods to send the data to your server as required etc.

}
```

There's also this method

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{

//Which you can use to listen for the @"\" return action if you prefer.

}
```

I hope this helps