# UITextView resignFirstResponder not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I'm trying to hide the keyboard after the user clicked on the return button of the keyboard.

I'm using this function to hide it:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range
 replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {

        [textView resignFirstResponder];

        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

When the textview is empty this function works but once there is a characters in the textview,nothing happens and the keyboard doesnt get hidden.

Comment: Does your code go through the `if` test?

Comment: Why would you use a text view instead of a text field if you are only going to allow one line of text?

Comment: You should probably be using UITextField instead. See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/704197/2708650

Comment: I have replicated your code and it works fine. My only thought is maybe you've declared an instance variable named `textView` and the code doesn't know whether to resign the local or instance `textView`. I added an `NSLog` statement before the `resignFirstResponder` line and it gets hit regardless of whether the text view contains other characters, or if the cursor is in the middle of the content.

Comment: Yes it does go through the if .
How the keyboard should  resign if i let the user write more then one line?

Comment: @Stonz2 The method parameter would take precedence of an ivar with the same name. There would be no confusion. Variable scope is clearly defined with no ambiguity.

Comment: @AvivPaz To dismiss the keyboard for a text view on an iPhone or iPod touch you can use an `inputAccessoryView` with a button that dismisses the keyboard.

Comment: I assume you've set yourself up as the delegate for the UITextView

Comment: yes of course , it wouldnt get to the shouldChangeTextInRange funtion if i wouldn't have.
It's really weird , when i debug it , it's going through the samme process if the textview is empty or if it's not but only when it's empty , the resign works

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use     `[self endEditing:YES];` or `self.view endEditing:YES]`

Comment: There is an important difference: `resignFirstResponder` accepts the pending autocorrection suggestion while `endEditing` does not.

Comment: Oh , didnt think about thought the problem is to remove the KB .

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Was my fault. I had a function which once the user finished editing i'm checking if it's empty or not. For some reason returned no instead of yes. Thanks for the help