# Swift Programming: Evaluate value in a string

Tags: cocoa, swift, enter, evaluate

My question is on SWIFT/COCOA programming. I want to evaluate the content inside a string. For example, I have 
    `var1 = "2 + 3"` 
Is there any inbuilt function in SWIFT/COCOA that can evaluate content in var1 and return `5`. I tried what I could understand from string interpolation but that is not helping

```
var myNum = "45/30"
var myNum2 = "sin(30)"
var myNum3 = "\(Float(myNum) * Float(myNum2))";

error: could not find member 'convertFromStringInterpolationSegment'
```

Also, got another question.. How do I detect Return key pressed in SWIFT? Any trigger similar to "`func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification)` "

Comment: Based on the second question, you're trying to create an application which solves math problems? You have a text field where the user inputs the problem?

Comment: Don't put two completely unrelated problems into one question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your second question, assuming you're using a `textField`, you can use the delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

This method is executed when the return key is pressed. If don't want to hide the keyboard, you need to return `NO` from this function at the end.

---

If you're using a `textView`, you can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703754/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-for-uitextview-with-return-key). You implement the `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` method of `UITextViewDelegate` and in that check if the replacement text is `\n`.

Comment: By the way does - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField work for Mac Program Development too? I don't see hint popping up when I am typing textFieldShouldReturn in XCODE.